# header title missing in jQuery mobile nested listview

Tags: jquery-mobile

The title header in my nested listview in jQuery Mobile is not showing. The docs say the nested header is taken from the parent listitem  or . When i use Firebug in Firefox to inspect the header i can see a blue bounding box were the title should be with a div with the class ui-title but the tag is empty.

Has anyone any idea if i can make it appear using an option in `mobileinit()` or something similar??

I have tried setting static text by testing using this code:

```
$(':jqmData(url^=results)').on('pagebeforecreate',function (event) {
  var title =  $(':jqmData(url^=results)').find(':jqmData(role=header) h1').html();
  $(this).filter(':jqmData(url*=ui-page)').find(':jqmData(role=header) h3').html('<h3>' + title + '</h3>');
});
```

Which may be close but its not doing anything either.

Comment: just a little tip, nested listview is deprecated as of 1.3.2 and will be removed on 1.4

Comment: @ Omar i saw this somewhere too - any idea what they'll be replacing it with (if anything). I was actually surprised this feature was possible at all - nested listviews are like the bad-old-days of nested tables in html - structural nightmares.

Comment: It's a listview converted into pages. You do it yourself easily.